# Transition after adding a class with jQuery isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got two columns of images, done with `column-count:2`. When I press one of the images, jQuery duplicates that image at the exact same position with `position:absolute`. Then a class `.dupAnim` gets added, which makes that image full width and transition it to `top:0;left:0` of the page.

---

So my problem:
When I click an image, the transition from the original state to `top:0; left:0; width:100%` isn't working. But when I click the close button, it's perfectly transitioning back.

It seems like the *in transition* isn't working, but the *out transition* is working. Below you can find a snippet. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```js
$(".item").each(function(){
  var imageSrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
  $(this).find('.clipped').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
  
  var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
  $(this).css('height', imgHeight + 'px');
});

$(".item").click(function(){
  
  $(this).clone().appendTo(".duplicated").addClass("dupe");
  var width = $(this).width();
  var height = $(this).height();
  var top = $(this).offset().top;
  var left = $(this).offset().left;
    
  var dupe = ".dupe";
  
  $(dupe).css({
    'width': width + 'px',
    'height': height + 'px',
    'top': top + 'px',
    'left': left + 'px',
    'position': 'fixed'
  });
  
  $(dupe).addClass("dupAnim");
  
  $(".portfolio-close").fadeIn();
  
});

$(".portfolio-close").click(function(){
  $(".duplicated").find(".dupAnim").removeClass("dupAnim");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".duplicated").children().remove();
  }, 500);
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 5% 10%;
}
.wrapper .page-title {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item .clipped {
  padding: 0 30px 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  background: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(0deg);
  /* change hue-rotate to play with tint */
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item .clipped .item-title {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item img {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .duplicated .dupe {
  position: fixed;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .duplicated .dupe.dupAnim {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .portfolio-close {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 21;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #515151;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 0 13px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div id="portfolio-items">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Yoga</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Elephant</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Bird</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">View</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Ailurus_fulgens_RoterPanda_LesserPanda-2.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Dog</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg">
    </div>
    
  <div class="duplicated"></div>
    
  <div class="portfolio-close">✕</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When element is added to dom or changed from "display: none", it appears in finished state of transition. This means that you have to add at least 17ms delay between adding an element and applying a transitioned class.

Comment: @RauliRajande When I add a timeout for adding the class, the transition isn't clean still :/ Tried that out aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to add the `fadeIn` and the addition of the `dupe` class as callbacks to the container being faded in. This ensures that the callback it not executed until after the first effect is complete.

Also, I've added: `$(".portfolio-close").hide();` at the beginning of the code to ensure that the container always starts off hidden because after clicking one item, it will be visible and you need it hidden for each click so that when it's class changes, the transition will work.

I reorganized the creation of the duplicate a little (to remove unnecessary variables and clean up the code a bit) and I added the `all` parameter to your `transition` properties:

```js
$(".item").each(function(){
  var imageSrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
  $(this).find('.clipped').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
  
  var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
  $(this).css('height', imgHeight + 'px');
});

$(".item").click(function(){
  
  var $clone = $(this).clone();
  
  // Make sure the container is hidden before the effects begin:
  $(".portfolio-close").hide();  

  $clone.appendTo(".duplicated");
  $clone.hide();  
  
  // Passing a function as the second argument to JQuery's show(),
  // hide(), fadeIn(), fadeOut(), etc. ensures that the function
  // is run AFTER the first effect is complete.
  $(".portfolio-close").fadeIn(50, function(){
    $clone.fadeIn();
    $clone.addClass("dupe");
  });    

  // No need to create varaibles for values you are only
  // going to access just once. Just get the values directly:
  $clone.css({
    'width': $(this).width() + 'px',
    'height': $(this).height() + 'px',
    'top': $(this).offset().top + 'px',
    'left': $(this).offset().left + 'px',
    'position': 'fixed'
  });

  $clone.addClass("dupAnim");   
});

$(".portfolio-close").click(function(){
  $(".duplicated").find(".dupAnim").removeClass("dupAnim");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".duplicated").children().remove();
  }, 500);
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 5% 10%;
}
.wrapper .page-title {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item .clipped {
  padding: 0 30px 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  background: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(0deg);
  /* change hue-rotate to play with tint */
  transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item .clipped .item-title {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item img {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .duplicated .dupe {
  position: fixed;
  transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .duplicated .dupe.dupAnim {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .portfolio-close {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 21;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #515151;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 0 13px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div id="portfolio-items">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Yoga</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Elephant</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Bird</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">View</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Ailurus_fulgens_RoterPanda_LesserPanda-2.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Dog</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg">
    </div>
    
  <div class="duplicated"></div>
    
  <div class="portfolio-close">✕</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed the lack of `all`, too, but W3C seems to think it's still valid CSS without it, and indeed it still works fine.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Yes, but better to include it for clarity.

Comment: It was just an observation, not a criticism. I would include it myself.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Understood. Just my reply. That's all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks alot for your answer. That makes sense. Instead of adding `$clone.fadeIn(); $clone.addClass("dupe");` as a callback function of fadeIn() of the close button, I just set a timeout, so the close button can fade in nicer. Additionally I changed the `$clone.fadeIn()` to `$clone.show()`, because the duplicated element was weirdly fading in on codepen. Working like a charm now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The transitions are working fine, it's just that your duplicates are not starting from the same shape/size as the original.

Answer (score 0):

Your `transition: .5s ease-in-out` for `.dupe` will invoke the transition when you modify the initial style (eg, modify the `width: 100%` of the image to `width + 'px'` which computed through js)  with the next code:

```

```
$(dupe).css({
'width': width + 'px',
'height': height + 'px',
'top': top + 'px',
'left': left + 'px',
'position': 'fixed',
```

})
```

Then if you immediately `addClass('dupAnim')`, it will override the former style modify(eg, set width to `100% !important`) so, you will not see the transition of the width.

So you can add a extra className for unset the transition before set the style computed through js, and then remove the className.

Add the more thing is that you need add a setTimeout when modify the className to invoke the reflow of the browser.

```js
$(".item").each(function(){
  var imageSrc = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
  $(this).find('.clipped').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
  
  var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
  $(this).css('height', imgHeight + 'px');
});

$(".item").click(function(){
  
  $(this).clone().appendTo(".duplicated").addClass("dupe");
  var width = $(this).width();
  var height = $(this).height();
  var top = $(this).offset().top;
  var left = $(this).offset().left;
    
  var dupe = ".dupe";
  
  $(dupe).addClass('no-transition').css({
    'width': width + 'px',
    'height': height + 'px',
    'top': top + 'px',
    'left': left + 'px',
    'position': 'fixed',
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
 $(dupe).removeClass('no-transition');
  }, 10);
 
  setTimeout(function() {
  $(dupe).addClass("dupAnim") 
    $(".portfolio-close").fadeIn(500);
  }, 30);
  
  
});

$(".portfolio-close").click(function(){
  $(".duplicated").find(".dupAnim").removeClass("dupAnim");
  setTimeout(function(){
  $(".duplicated").children().remove();
  }, 500);
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 5% 10%;
}
.wrapper .page-title {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item .clipped {
  padding: 0 30px 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  background: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(0deg);
  /* change hue-rotate to play with tint */
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item .clipped .item-title {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .item img {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .duplicated .dupe {
  position: fixed;
}
.no-transition {
  transition: unset !important;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .duplicated .dupe.dupAnim {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper #portfolio-items .portfolio-close {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 21;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #515151;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0 0 13px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div id="portfolio-items">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Yoga</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Elephant</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Bird</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">View</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Ailurus_fulgens_RoterPanda_LesserPanda-2.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="clipped">
        <h1 class="item-title">Dog</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg">
    </div>
    
  <div class="duplicated"></div>
    
  <div class="portfolio-close">✕</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you could just place that code inside a callback to `fadeIn`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that out aswell, but here's the problem that the width of the duplicated object doesn't transition tho

Comment: @TobiasGlaus See my answer below.

Comment: I would suggest to avoid fadeIn and other js animations, as they make your page slower. This is perfectly doable in css.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus  Still need something to modify. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update you jQuery and add a SetTimeout() when adding the dupAnim class, then wrap() the duplicate img with a new container.

```
$(".item").click(function(){
  // changed the container
  $(this).clone().appendTo(".duplicated").wrap('<span class="img-container dupe">');
  var width = $(this).width();
  var height = $(this).height();
  var top = $(this).offset().top;
  var left = $(this).offset().left; 
  var dupe = ".dupe";
   $(dupe).css({
    'width': width + 'px',
    'height': height + 'px',
    'top': top + 'px',
    'left': left + 'px',
    'position': 'fixed',
  });
 // settime out
  setTimeout(function(){    
        $(dupe).addClass("dupAnim");
  },100) ; 

 $(".portfolio-close").fadeIn();

});

$(".portfolio-close").click(function(){
  $(".duplicated").find(".dupAnim").removeClass("dupAnim");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".duplicated").children().remove();
  }, 500);
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: No need for `setTimeout`. `fadeIn()` takes a callback as its second argument for just this purpose.